# Where to ask question about hardware?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know where to address my question. It is about hardware - I need to know which is the recommended hardware (PC).

Which is the site in which I can ask my question?

My question will be:

> Where to find info about hardware required to make hackintosh?

I need specific models of MB and CPU - for best compatibilty.

Comment: Possibly [su], but you're a little vague here. How about [edit]ing your question here with a sample question you'd like to ask?

Comment: recommendations about what to buy are going to be off topic on any site.

Comment: I need a reference where to look. I know that Intel cpu + mobo will be OK. Just try to avoid compatibility issues.

Comment: pcpartpicker.com (in this case, probably their forums) might be a good place to check out - or if people have a hackintosh build listed on the completed builds page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to ask this question on the [meta](http://meta.superuser.com) of [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Why? Because hardware questions are on-topic there, so it seems the place to go. I am just a little worried about this sentence describing what is off-topic:

> asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation

I am not sure if your question will be categorized as such since it isn't a really hardware shopping list question although it can be seen as that, so to make sure if you can ask it there, ask on their meta.

Answer (score 3):

The [Hardware Recommendations](//area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) site is expected to launch soon.  Maybe not soon enough, if your question is urgent, but if you are a hardware enthusiast you may be interested in joining the launch.